# Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)

Tags: r, keras

I am working with keras library in R, and we obtain the following error:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords): 
TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'keras.engine.sequential.Sequential'> to Tensor. Contents: <keras.engine.sequential.Sequential object at 0x000000005491C2E8>. Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

The source code in which I get this failure is as follows:

```
conv_base <- application_vgg16(include_top = FALSE, input_shape = c(150, 150, 3))
```

Anybody could help me to fix it??
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that is **all** the code?

Comment: No, it is not, but there is no error in the previous lines. Finally I could solve the problem downgrading keras version from 2.2.0 to 2.1.6, but I do not know exactly why the most recent version generates this error.